# how to run ajax from Drop down item in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Good Morning,
I am new to coding and learning laravel for home project. I am trying to get data from database as per dropdown selection. The code for dropdown item is as below

```
<div class="dropdown">

            <button class="btn p-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="bx bx-dots-vertical-rounded"></i>
            </button>

            <div id="milkstatementdropdown" name="milkstatementdropdown"class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu- end" aria-labelledby="milkstatementdropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Yesterday</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Last 7 Days</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Last Month</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Last 3 Month</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Last 6 Month</a></li>
            </div>

          </div>
```

`
After selection of drop down item, need to get value and then pass the same to controller using AJAX.

below is the script for getting the selection value and process ajax.

`

```
 $("#milkstatementdropdown").change(function(){
                  var duration = $(this).val();
                  alert(course);

                  // ajax call


                });
```

`

i am not able to get the Alert..

Did i miss something and make mistake in code...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `#milkstatementdropdown` is a `div`, there is no `change` event for a `div`.  Are you using a library or external resource to make the `div` a dropdown?

Comment: I m using free dashboard of "Sneat"...

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$('#id').on('select2:close', function () {
    //do anything
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one // You can use Anything

```
$('#milkstatementdropdown li a').on('click', function(){
      alert($(this).text());
      //do anything
});
```

Comment: Thanks U.. but nothing happening. No alert or error showing...

Comment: @RahulW...Can you check console with li element...what value you get in response...?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use onClick beacuase your dropdown is not an Select Tag:-

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="get_data('Yesterday')">Yesterday</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="get_data('Last 7 Days')">Last 7 Days</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="get_data('Last Month')">Last Month</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="get_data('Last 3 Month')">Last 3 Month</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="get_data('Last 6 Month')">Last 6 Month</a></li>
```

And then in your Javascript part you have make get_data function to hanle onClick event.

```
function get_data(duration){
    // Now you can get data from controller according to received 'duration'
   // ajax call
}
```